# accessing RadListView from button inside ng-template button nativescript angular

Tags: angular, nativescript

How to access parent listview (RadListView) index when button is tap

need to access listview indext from button inside ng-template, but cant get any direction how to do it'

i try args.object.parent but no luck .

```
<RadListView row="0" [items]="dataItems" selectionBehavior="Press"
     (itemDeselected)="onItemDeselected($event)" (itemDeselected)="onItemDeselected($event)"
     multipleSelection="true" *ngIf="!restoClose" >
            <ng-template let-dish="item" let-i="index"  >
                <GridLayout orientation="horizontal" class="list-group-item m-5 "
                    rows="auto" columns="auto,*,auto">
                    <Image col="0" row="0" [src]="dish.image" height="30"
                        width="30"></Image>
                    <StackLayout col="1" row="0" marginLeft="15">
                        <Label marginTop="5" paddingRight="5" [text]="dish.name"
                            class="list-group-item-heading"
                            color="#333333"></Label>
                        <Label marginTop="5" [text]="dish.description" color="#999999" textWrap="true"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <Button col="2" width="80" horizontalAlignment="right" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded-lg" 
                    text="{{ dish.price | number:'1.2' }}" (tap)="onItemSelecting($event)"></Button>
                </GridLayout>
            </ng-template>
    </RadListView>
```

// this is component

```
public onItemSelecting(args) {
    console.log('want to access from here', args.object.parent);
    const listview = args.object.parent as RadListView;
    const selectedItems = listview.getSelectedItems() as Array<TfmenuItem>;
    let selectedTitles = "Selecting item: ";
    for (let i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
        selectedTitles += selectedItems[i] ? selectedItems[i].name : "";

        if (i < selectedItems.length - 1) {
            selectedTitles += ", ";
        }
    }

    const selectedItem = this.dataItems.getItem(args.index);
    console.log("Item selecting: " + (selectedItem && selectedItem.name));
}
```

i expect to access the listview index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link the list view

```
<RadListView #myListView>
```

And then in the controller add it as

```
@ViewChild('myListView', {static: false}) listViewComponent: RadListViewComponent;
```

Comment: if i use this listViewComponent.getSelectedItems() is not function, i want to access the listview as RadListView so i can get index

Comment: `listViewComponent.listView` should give you the `RadListView`. So you may call `listViewComponent.listView.getSelectedItems();`

Comment: sorry for not make clear description. this.listViewComponent   does give .getSelectedItem() because it declared as : RadListView but when i run the error show that .getDSelectedItem is not function

Comment: @Manoj thank you for pointing that RadListView is component so i need to use .listView